# Why is the connection to my NAS really slow/unstable via local network IP but not via dyndns-IP?

Tags: macbook-pro, unix, nas

I'm having a problem to connect my Macbook Air to my NAS. The NAS has Debian installed and can be reached by any other computer in the network.

I can find the NAS on Finder. The NAS is listed in the sidebar as shared. But when I try to connect to see the shared files it takes ages to connect and most of the times it times out.

The same happens when I try to access some services that are running in the NAS like its admin platform or when I try to connect via SSH.

I've configured a dyndns pointing to the NAS and when I try to access the NAS using the dyndns-IP instead of the local network IP it works fine and much faster.

I think that there's something messed with the network in my Mac since I can connect stable and fast from my iPhone or other Windows devices.

Any advice would be great.

Comment: Are you connecting via the network name, or directly by the network IP?

Comment: How do you connect to your NAS ? Wifi ?? Ethernet Cable (through router or hub) ?? How do the other devices connect to it? After what time does it time out ? Are you just trying to find or look for files or are you trying to work with them ? There could be many factors why it would have a slow speed.  Do you use SMB or AFP ??? What version of OS X do you have installed ?

Comment: @KyleCronin Directly via the IP

Comment: @shitake83 The Macbook is connected wi-fi through a hub connected in a router. I wondered if it could be something with the wireless but I can connect from my iPhone without problems... Times out after approx. 1 min.. Just find them... SMB, but I tried with AFP as well. OS X 10.7.3

Comment: Not sure how or why but it suddenly started to work fine tonight... I'll keep looking to see if something happens. Thanks!

Comment: sometimes computers are jerks too. I'm happy you've solved your problem. Or better said it automagically left ^^.

Comment: I've a similar problem since 10.7.3, my connection to the LAN via SMB is extremely slow. I've tried many things but nothing solves the issue. Bug reported to Apple.